# Write tf.dataset back to TFRecord

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

After creating a tf.data.Dataset, I would like to write it to TFRecords.

One way to do that is to iterate through the complete dataset and write after serializeToString into TFRecords. But it is not the most efficient way to do it.

Are there easier ways to do this?
Are there any APIs available in TF2.0?

Answer (score 7):

You could use [TensorFlow Datasets (tfds)](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets): this library is not only a collection of ready to use `tf.data.Dataset` objects, but it is also a toolchain for the transformation of raw data to TFRecords.

Following the [official guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/blob/master/docs/add_dataset.md) is straightforward adding a new dataset. In short, you only have to implement the methods `_info` and `_generate_examples`.

In particular, the `_generate_examples` is the method that is used by tfds to create rows inside the TFRecords.
Every element that `_generate_examples` yields is a dictionary; every dictionary is a row in a TFRecord file.

For example (kept from the official documentation) the `generate_examples` below is used by tfds to save TFRecords, each one with the records "image_description", "image", "label".

```py
def _generate_examples(self, images_dir_path, labels):
  # Read the input data out of the source files
  for image_file in tf.io.gfile.listdir(images_dir_path):
    ...
  with tf.io.gfile.GFile(labels) as f:
    ...

  # And yield examples as feature dictionaries
  for image_id, description, label in data:
    yield image_id, {
        "image_description": description,
        "image": "%s/%s.jpeg" % (images_dir_path, image_id),
        "label": label,
    }
```

In your case, you can just use the `tf.data.Dataset` object you already have, and loop through it (in the generate_examples method), and yielding the rows of the TFRecord.

In this way, tfds will take care for you of the serialization and you'll find in the `~/tensorflow_datasets` folder the TFRecord created for your dataset.

Comment: Yes, this is an option. But I wanted to avoid iterating through the complete dataset. 
Instead, to iterate through a BatchedDataset (of shapes, for ex: LSTM input : 250,8,6) and may be serialize that? I dont know if that would work.

Comment: It will work, you can create tfrecords with records with shape (250, 8, 6) each. Just loop over the batcheddataset and write every batch